# What is the origin of “tyrolienne” for zip line?

Tags: étymologie

I recently learned the word “tyrolienne” and I’m curious as to why it means zip line? Does it come from Tyrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It originates from Tyrol, precisely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrolean_traverse